# jquery xml parse empty issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

This is the xml file i want to parse.

```
    <channel>
    <title>TeknoSeyir</title>
    <atom:link href="https://teknoseyir.com/feed" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
    <link>https://teknoseyir.com</link>
    <description>Her gün on dakika teknoloji molası...</description>
    <lastBuildDate>Sun, 08 Jul 2018 05:19:10 +0000</lastBuildDate>
    <language>tr-TR</language>
    <sy:updatePeriod>hourly</sy:updatePeriod>
    <sy:updateFrequency>1</sy:updateFrequency>

    <item>
        <title>Haftalık Gündem Değerlendirmesi 2018/27</title>
        <link>https://teknoseyir.com/haftalik-gundem-degerlendirmesi-2018-27</link>
        <comments>https://teknoseyir.com/haftalik-gundem-degerlendirmesi-2018-27#comments</comments>
        <pubDate>Fri, 06 Jul 2018 20:32:07 +0000</pubDate>
        <dc:creator><![CDATA[TeknoSeyir]]></dc:creator>
                <category><![CDATA[Gündem]]></category>
        <category><![CDATA[gündem değerlendirmesi]]></category>
        <category><![CDATA[haftalık gündem]]></category>
        <category><![CDATA[teknoloji sohbeti]]></category>

        <guid isPermaLink="false">https://teknoseyir.com/?p=908864</guid>
        <description><![CDATA[<p>TeknoSeyir editörleri geçtiğimiz haftanın gündemini değerlendiriyor.</p>
<p>The post <a rel="nofollow" href="https://teknoseyir.com/haftalik-gundem-degerlendirmesi-2018-27">Haftalık Gündem Değerlendirmesi 2018/27</a> appeared first on <a rel="nofollow" href="https://teknoseyir.com">TeknoSeyir</a>.</p>
]]></description>
```

i wan to parse this section `<p>TeknoSeyir editörleri geçtiğimiz haftanın gündemini değerlendiriyor.</p>`

This is my jquery code returns empty.

```
      $.get('https://teknoseyir.com/feed', function (data) {
      $(data).find("description").each(function () { 
          var el = $(this);




         console.log(el.find("p").text());

      });      
  });
}
```

How can i parse

TeknoSeyir editörleri geçtiğimiz haftanın gündemini değerlendiriyor.

section using jquery?

Comment: Your XML is not valid to parse.

Comment: @SalmenBejaoui what dou you  mean i can parse title,link and pubdate etc

Comment: probably you have the full xml. Btw you parse it find all p tag e select the first one with eq(0)